# How to generate Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: java, android, fibonacci

```
private TextView tvOutput;

 int[]feld = new int[30];
        feld[0]=0;
        feld[1]=1;

        for(int i=2; i<30; i++){
            feld[i]=feld[i-2]+feld[i-1];

            tvOutput.setText   (Integer.toString(feld[i]));
        }
```

The code overwrites my var i with each loop thus the program merely shows the last number in the end. But it is supposed to show all thirty numbers. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you keep overriding the `text` property of your `tvOutput` on each iteration of your loop. It shows the last number because `tvOutput.setText(Integer.toString(feld[29]))` is the last time `setText` is called. Instead remove it from the loop and pass in the array converted into a string:

```
    int[]feld = new int[30];
    feld[0]=0;
    feld[1]=1;

    for(int i=2; i<30; i++) {
        feld[i]=feld[i-2]+feld[i-1];
    }

    tvOutput.setText(Arrays.toString(feld));
```